# Как добавить метку на объекты(клиники, заправки, кафе, остановки итд) в ymaps?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Использую api яндекс карты 2.1. Этот код при клике добавляет метки на карту.

```js
    ymaps.ready(init)


    function init() {
        let map = new ymaps.Map('popup__content__map', {
            center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
            zoom: 9
        }, {
            searchControlNoPlacemark: true
        });

        map.events
            .add('click', (e) => {
                let coords = e.get('coords');
                map.geoObjects.removeAll();
                map.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark(coords));
            });
    }
```

Но при клике на

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

клиники, заправки, кафе, остановки  итд, открывается `балун`. **Как сделать так, чтобы на другие объекты можно было ставить метки?(при клике)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете отключить интерактивность нативных меток карты, тогда можно будет кликать куда угодно и обрабатывать свои ивенты - эти метки перестанут быть кликабельными.

```
let map = new ymaps.Map("map_area", {
    center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
    zoom: 9
}, {
    yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity: true
});
```